# Find Number what I selected

Tags: puzzle

I have randomly selected a number between 1 and 1200 in my mind. If you can only ask questions for which I will only reply with “yes” or “no”, how many questions will you need to ask before you arrive at the answer for the number I’ve selected in my mind ?

Comment: At least one. Why is this tagged JavaScript?

Comment: My guess is you're thinking of Pi.

Comment: ceil(log(1200)/log(2)) = 11

Comment: infinite, since no one said anything about the numbers being integers. :)

Comment: do you mean to ask what the maximum number of questions is to guarantee that you will arrive at the answer? something like is the number > 600, yes, is the number > 900... ???

Comment: The answer depends on how often you change your mind about your number.

Comment: Even with floating point numbers, it wouldn't be infinite, since there is a finite number of floating point numbers between 1 and 1200. Oh wait, they just removed the "javascript" tag, so it's no longer a computer question. Never mind then.

Answer (score 5):

Look up binary search. Thats what you are looking for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

In the above link, look up *Number Guessing Game*

Answer (score 1):

It has already been pointed out that this is discussed in the wikipedia page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm.

Let's look at it in a little more detail to see if it is in fact true that the answer is ceil(log(1200)/log(2)=11.  For this to be true, we have to show two things:

1. it is possible to identify the number in 11 questions
2. it is not possible to identify the number in less than 11 questions

for (1):

it's enough to give the algorithm which is, as everyone stated, binary search.  for example:

- is less than 1024
- if yes, is it less than 512,
  etc.

to give an intuition: suppose the number is 3, then we have < 1024 (1 question), < 512 (2), < 256 (3), < 128 (4), < 64 (5), < 32 (6), < 16 (7), < 8 (8), < 4 (9), (not) < 2 (10), < 3 (11).

does this work?  i won't show this rigorously, but suppose the number you are thinking of is x = a[10]*1+...a[0]*2^10 (binary representation).  observe that you start asking is it less than 2^10, then for nth, you ask is it less than sum(a[j]*2^(10-j)+2^(10-n), j=0...n-1).  observe that for each ith question, if the answer is yes, then a[i-1] = 0 (otherwise a[i-1]=1).  after 11 questions (i=0,...10), you will have uncovered all a[0]...a[10].

for (2), [again, not rigorous]

suppose you asked N questions.  from these N questions, you can only deduce 2^N numbers because there are only 2^N possible ways in which the answers can be made.  suppose N < 11, then 2^N <= 1024 < 1200.  so by Pigeon Hole principle, you can't uniquely identify all 1200 numbers with N<11.

In fact, this line of argument (#2) is used to show that comparison sort cannot be faster than O(n log n).

now, it would be good if some one can make this rigorous :p  can also be generalized to M instead of 1200.

Ok, so that is easy enough, what if you are allowed to ask: is a number y constructed by a complicated formula, less than, equal to, or greater than a number z constructed by a complicated formula? (answer can be less than, equal to, or greater than) how many questions do you need?

Comment: funny, I don't remember writing this answer.... must be amnesia.